# error "object invoked has disconnected" in 7.70 64 bits (was working in 32 bits)

Tags: excel, vba, saprfc, bapi

I have VBA in Excel 32 bits that can upload Sales Orders into SAP ERP software.  In order to get the code to run on 64 bits Excel, I uninstalled current SAP GUI and installed SAP GUI 7.70.  I now get an error:

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
>
> Automation error
> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Here is a code snapshot with error at line `sap_sales_order = boOrder.SalesDocument`:

```
'Call the method
boOrder.CreateFromDat2 orderheaderin:=boHeader, _
                       ordertext:=boText, _
                       orderpartners:=boPartner, _
                       orderitemsin:=boItemin, _
                       orderschedulesin:=boSchedin, _
                       orderconditionsin:=boCondin, _
                       Return:=oReturn

sap_sales_order = boOrder.SalesDocument

'Check if a error-message was returned
bError = False
```

I just referenced the 4 new DLL's in VBA... No Change.

Comment: Please note that pictures of code don't work here - instead [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: download latest patch. Insert wait after createfromdat2. login to gui before launching excel.

Comment: I edited the question to turn the code image into text

Comment: and post always full code with declarations, not just the acting piece. It matters

Comment: Thank you all, @david, I am on 770. i paused the code for 40 seconds after the above CreateFromDat2. Same error.

Comment: Please tell us which 7.70 patch level it is, which DLLs you are referring to (including the path), and as Suncatcher said, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like very simple example with `BAPI_BANK_CREATE` which is very simple and should work for everyone (minimal info with country, code and name)

Comment: Thank you all for your help!  I am on SAP GUI for Windows 7.70 (Patch 0)

Comment: Now on Patch 4.  (Rebooted).  I Added to References the 4 .ocx controls from C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SapGui\.  I initiated a :45 second pause after the   
boOrder.CreateFromDat2 orderheaderin:=boHeader, _
                               ordertext:=boText, _
                               orderpartners:=boPartner, _
                               orderitemsin:=boItemin, _
                               orderschedulesin:=boSchedin, _
                               orderconditionsin:=boCondin, _
                               Return:=oReturn  Line

Answer (score 0):

I see that the [SAP note 2153672](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2153672) ("SAP GUI BAPI : Error Message "Automation Error -2147417848 The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" displayed") says:

> It happens when a corrupt BAPI object is trying to query a member attribute or method or a key field.

and to install the latest SAP GUI patch.

So, if you have already installed the latest SAP GUI 7.70 patch, please contact the SAP support.